# Hanging 10 pictures in a line, but two of them cannot be next to them. How many way can this be done?

Tags: combinatorics

How can I hang 10 different pictures in a line. I do not want two specific pictures to be hung next to each other how many ways are there for me to hang my pictures?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let the specific pictures be $P$ and $Q$. Imagine that they’ve been hung with $P$ to the left of $Q$. Now you have to hang the other $8$ pictures; some can go before $P$, at least one must go between $P$ and $Q$, and some can go after $Q$. If $a$ go before $P$, $b+1$ go between $P$ and $Q$, and $c$ go after $Q$, we must have $a+b+c=7$; conversely, if $a,b$, and $c$ are non-negative integers whose sum is $7$, hanging $a$ pictures to the left of $P$, $b+1$ between $P$ and $Q$, and $c$ to the right of $Q$ is an acceptable arrangement of the pictures. We’d like to know, therefore, how many solutions $a+b+c=7$ has in non-negative integers. This is a standard [stars-and-bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29); the link gives both a formula and a pretty decent explanation of why it works.

Note that this figure takes into account only the **numbers** of pictures before $P$, between $P$ and $Q$, and after $Q$, not the identities of the pictures; no matter what $a,b$, and $c$ are, you can permute the other $8$ pictures in any order, and you’ll have to take this into account. You’ll also have to take into account that we could just as well hang $Q$ to the left of $P$.

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore the restriction, there are clearly $10!$ ways of hanging the pictures in a line, but this includes all the ways the two specific pictures can be hung together, of which there are $2\cdot9!$ ways:  think of bundling the two specific pictures together, which can be done in $2$ ways, depending on which one you place to the left of the other, and then placing the resulting $9$ objects in a line, which can be done in $9!$ ways.  So the number you want is

$$10!-2\cdot9!= (10-2)9! = 8\cdot9! = 2,903,040$$